# Retrieving multiple queries from mysql using WHILE,&&Operator (NOT USING JOIN)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, html-table

First of all i dont want to use JOIN
what am doing is fetching multiple queries through MySqli_Fetch_array(), The problem here is that because of the AND OPERATOR if any one of the MySqli_Fetch_array() is completed it stops all other and gives incomplete result of other  tables. If am putting OR operator thats also not appropriate because if the first condition gives true it wont execute other.
 This is my generalized code for you people to understand
HELPP AM STUCK HERE BADLY

```
while (($ans4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4))&&($ans5=mysqli_fetch_array($result5))&&($ans3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3))&&($ans1= mysqli_fetch_array($result1))&&($ans2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))) {

      echo "<tr>";

     echo  "   <td>".$ans1['name']."</td> ";
     echo  "   <td>".$ans2['id']."</td> ";
     echo  "   <td>".$ans3['company']."</td> ";
     echo  "   <td>".$ans4['owner']."</td> ";
     echo  "   <td>".$ans5['Oid']."</td> ";

      echo "</tr>";

    }
```

Comment: why are you running that many queries in parallel? If the queries are sucking data from the same tables, there's probably NO reason you couldn't do them all at the same time, e.g `select name from sometable`, `select id from sometable`, etc... could just be `select name, id, company, owner, Oid from sometable`

Comment: You must just change the way you do your queries...That is not the correct way....Your way will only work when all queries return the same number of results

Comment: @MarcB no all the tables are different basically what i am doing is fetching sepcific columns from different  table1 table2 table3 table4 table5 and displayinf them in one html table

Comment: @GeorgePant no all the tables are different basically what i am doing is fetching sepcific columns from different table1 table2 table3 table4 table5 and displayinf them in one html table

Comment: so why fetch them all in a single line? do multiple lines, one fetch each, and then do whatever "does this have a value" test afterwards.

Comment: @MarcB sorry i didn't get you

Comment: `$x = fetch(); $y = fetch(); if ($x) { do something } if ($y) { domsething }` separate the fetching logic from the display logic.

Comment: what's wrong with a join ? oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of doing queries is certainly not optimal since you could certainly achieve what you want doing less queries or altering your database design.You do 5 queries in order to get 5 fields that seem to be related.....

That beign said you could try using bitwise `OR` operator `$a | $b` to avoid short circuit evaluation.

```
while (($ans4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) |($ans5=mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) | ($ans3=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) | ($ans1= mysqli_fetch_array($result1))|($ans2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))) {
```

Comment: Thank You So much brother!! Worked for me

Comment: Happy I could help you